# Getting wrong data from relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have 2 tables:

DesignGroup table:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+
|            DesignGroupId             |  Name  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| 9D32C543-24EA-497E-918E-387C8A66BF1A | Group1 |
| 532C543E-24EA-497E-918E-387C8A66BF1A | Group2 |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

Design table:

```
+-----------+---------------+--------------------------------------+
| DesignKey |     Name      |            DesignGroupId             |
+-----------+---------------+--------------------------------------+
|         1 | Design        | 9D32C543-24EA-497E-918E-387C8A66BF1A |
|         2 | Design        | 9D32C543-24EA-497E-918E-387C8A66BF1A |
|         3 | AnotherDesign | 532C543E-24EA-497E-918E-387C8A66BF1A |
+-----------+---------------+--------------------------------------+
```

As you can see multiple designs can have same DesignGroupId, So I make a query like:

```
DECLARE @DesignName VARCHAR(255) = 'Design'

SELECT 
    [D].[Name] AS [Display],
    [D].[DesignKey] AS [Value]
FROM 
    [Design] AS [D]
JOIN 
    [DesignGroup] AS [DG] ON [D].[DesignGroupId] = [DG].[DesignGroupId]
GROUP BY
    [D].[Name], [D].[DesignKey];
```

My desire result of this, is get only one value one [Display] and one [Value] of each DesignGroupId, so my desire result there was:

```
+---------------+-------+
|    Display    | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Design        |     1 |
| AnotherDesign |     3 |
+---------------+-------+
```

But I'm getting result foreach DesignKey like:

```
+---------------+-------+
|    Display    | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Design        |     1 |
| Design        |     2 |
| AnotherDesign |     3 |
+---------------+-------+
```

How can I solve this? Regards

Comment: Why do you want `1` instead of `2` (or both)? What logic did you use, as a human, to decide on one over the other? Is it just "pick a random `designkey`"? or "Pick the smallest `designkey`"?

Comment: Grouping without aggregation does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need to join the tables. 
The results you want depend only on the data from the table `[Design]`.
So `GROUP BY [Name]` and get the minimum value of `[DesignKey]`:

```
SELECT 
    [Name] AS [Display],
    MIN([DesignKey]) AS [Value]
FROM [Design]
GROUP BY [Name];
```

But this will be fine if the table has only one value for `DesignGroupId`.
What do you need as a result for the other `DesignGroupId`s?
Maybe `GROUP BY [DesignGroupId], [Name]`:

```
SELECT 
    [DesignGroupId], 
    [Name] AS [Display],
    MIN([DesignKey]) AS [Value]
FROM [Design]
GROUP BY [DesignGroupId], [Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your objective to get the minimum DesignKey value for each Name (Display) and Group? You can wrap your result into a minimum value outer query:

```
SELECT DISPLAY, MIN(VALUE) from (
SELECT 
    [D].[Name] AS [Display],
    [D].[DesignKey] AS [Value]
FROM 
    [Design] AS [D]
JOIN 
    [DesignGroup] AS [DG] ON [D].[DesignGroupId] = [DG].[DesignGroupId]
GROUP BY
    [D].[Name], [D].[DesignKey])
GROUP BY Display;
```